# SQL Server constraint to check other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Product: SQL Server

Is it possible to write a constraint, that checks the values of other columns? In my specific case I will give you an example:

Let's imagine I have a table with 5 Columns:

```
Name | Hobby1 | Hobby2 | Hobby3 | Hobby4
```

Lets say there are the following values in it:

```
John Doe| fishing | reading| swimming| jogging
```

What I try to reach is the following:
If someone trys to  Insert : John Doe, fishing,reading

It should be blocked, cause I don't want the same combination in the first 3 Columns.

Can I realise that with a constraint or do I need a Primary key combination for the first 3 columns?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Poor table design. Have one hobby column, and several rows instead.

Comment: Create a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT with the three columns that you are referring to be unique, though you could think of a better design.

Comment: That was just to simplify the matter, I dont have such a table structure in my DB. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes, Primary key including first 3 columns may be exactly the constraint you need. Alternatively it should be UNIQUE constraint if some of them are nullable, plus  PRIMARY on `name NOT NULL` only.

Comment: Yes of course i need this feature, cause my 3rd column can sometimes be NULL. Can you secify this please? So the idea with the Primary key was not good for this usecase

Comment: @jarlh: when the requirement is always have exactly five hobbies then the OP's design is superior because SQL Server cannot check constraints across rows (but can across columns of the same row).

Comment: Have constraints to make sure hobby1 < hobby2 < ... hobby5, i.e alphabetic order.

Comment: How you are going to inserting data in to your table? if by procedure you can add a data existence check inside your procedure before the insert.. Otherwise you can set up unique check constraint across all three columns.

Comment: As @jarlh has mentioned poor table design. Have a table where you have names and create an id column. Create another table to store hobbies. Create third table to store mapping of names to hobbies.

Answer (score 1):

Add unique constraint to your table for first three columns.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT UK_Name_Hobby1_Hobby2 UNIQUE (Name, Hobby1,Hobby2);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What if there are NULLS in my third column? can i overcome this so that : John Doe, fishing, NULL ; John Doe, fishing, NULL will be accepted?

Comment: Unique constraint allow null once

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could do as @jarlh says (in comments) and ensure the hobby columns are ordered and this will satisfy your requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE Hobbies
(
 Name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 Hobby1 VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 Hobby2 VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
 Hobby3 VARCHAR(35),
 Hobby4 VARCHAR(35),
 CHECK ( Hobby1 < Hobby2 ),
 CHECK ( Hobby2 < Hobby3 ),
 CHECK ( Hobby3 < Hobby4 ),
 UNIQUE ( Name, Hobby1, Hobby2 ),
);
```

...However, this would allow the following which feels like it should be invalid data:

```
INSERT INTO Hobbies VALUES ( 'John Doe', 'fishing', 'jogging', 'reading', 'swimming' );
INSERT INTO Hobbies VALUES ( 'John Doe', 'jogging', 'reading', 'swimming', NULL );
```